Google Sheets Vertical Lookup in Conjuction with Summation
Creating a tip-tracking spreadsheet. Using Google Sheets.
In the workbook, I have one sheet (Data) where a name may appear multiple times. I have another sheet (Summary) that is exported. The Summary sheet list a name in one cell, and a formula in an adjacent cell that searches the other sheet for the values corresponding to the 'search-key' and then adds them up.
I have been trying =VLOOKUP(A5,Data!B8:B23,Data!AD1:AD23) so that if the search-key matches on the Data sheet in the corresponding range, it'll return the value found in the totals column (Data!AD1:A23).
Basically, if "Smith, John" is found in the Data sheet in the B column, it'll return the "$1" found in the AD column of the same row "Smith, John" is found in. However, all I am getting is a "VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range." error message.
From there, I want to be able to sum all the instances in which "Smith, John" appears in the B Column and the resultant AD value.
If I can get the first part to work, would it then look like =((=VLOOKUP(A5,Data!B8:B23,Data!AD1:AD23)+(=VLOOKUP(A5,Data!B25:B43,Data!AD25:AD43))?
I've tried LOOKUP as well as VLOOKUP functions. I've tried changing the 'index' to just read Data!AD so that it might go the entire column. I've tried changing the 'search-key' to not be a cell but instead the exact name in parentheses (and out of parentheses).

Instead of using VLOOKUP, it might make more sense to use MAP and SUMIF. Something like this, but it's hard to tell without seeing how it's set up specifically.
=MAP(A5:A,lambda(k,sumif(Data!B:B,k,Data!:AD:AD)))


First, vlookup() doesn't work on that way. Second, your range has mismatch size like Data!B8:B23, Data!AD1:AD23, here two range size must be same height. So, both range will be Data!B1:B23, Data!AD1:AD23. Now, use XLOOKUP() like-
=XLOOKUP(A5,Data!B1:B23,Data!AD1:AD23)

But above formula will only return first occurrence. If you have more than one entry, then use SUMIFS() or FILTER() then SUM() function like-
=SUMIFS(Data!AD1:AD23,Data!B8:B23,A5)

or using FILTER() like-
=SUM(FILTER(Data!AD1:AD23,Data!B8:B23=A5))

Finally, make it dynamic spill array use BYROW() or MAP() function in this way-
=BYROW(A5:A,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",SUMIFS(Data!AD:AD,Data!B:B,r))))

